# Get all select/option lists start by something

Tags: javascript, dom, jsni

In an HTML page i have severals list.

```
<select name="salut-1358937506000-OK">
<option selected="" value="OK">OK</option>
<option value="OK">NOK</option>
</select>

<select name="salut-1358937582000-OK">
<option selected="" value="OK">OK</option>
<option value="OK">NOK</option>
</select>
...
```

In javascript, I want to get all select/option list which started by "salut-".
For theses list, i want to compare his name and his selected value.

I know it is possible in jQuery but can't use jquery, only javascript (JSNI with GWT exactly).

Have you an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var selects = document.getElementsByTagName('select');
var sel;
var relevantSelects = [];
for(var z=0; z<selects.length; z++){
     sel = selects[z];
     if(sel.name.indexOf('salut-') === 0){
         relevantSelects.push(sel);
     }
}
console.log(relevantSelects);
```

Comment: Thanks you, i will addapt your code in JSN ($doc for document for example).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) function to get each `SELECT` name, for example:

```
var e = document.getElementsByTagName("select");
for (var i = 0; i < e.length; i++){
  var name = e[i].getAttribute("name");
}
```

Then you can use the following code to get each `OPTION` for the `SELECT`, to do any necessary comparisons:

```
var options = e[i].getElementsByTagName("option")
```